# List of registered group in XMPP?

Tags: ios, xmpp, chat, xmppframework

How can I retrieve the Group list using XMPPFramework?

I am using this code:

```
NSXMLElement *adminElement = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"iq"];
XMPPJID *roomJid = [XMPPJID jidWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@conference.%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"username"],@"server_address"]];
XMPPRoomMemoryStorage *roomMemoryStorage = [[XMPPRoomMemoryStorage alloc] init];
XMPPRoom * xmppRoom = [[XMPPRoom alloc]
                       initWithRoomStorage:roomMemoryStorage
                       jid:roomJid
                       dispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

[adminElement addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[xmppRoom roomJID]]];
[adminElement addAttributeWithName:@"id" stringValue:@"adminlist"];
[adminElement addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"get"];
NSXMLElement *queryElement = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"query"];
[queryElement addAttributeWithName:@"xmlns" stringValue:@"http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin"];
NSXMLElement *itemElement = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"item"];
[itemElement addAttributeWithName:@"affiliation" stringValue:@"admin"];
[queryElement addChild:itemElement];
[adminElement addChild:queryElement];
[xmppStream sendElement:adminElement];
```

Comment: `XMPPJID *servrJID = [XMPPJID jidWithString:@"server_address"];
    XMPPIQ *iq = [XMPPIQ iqWithType:@"get" to:servrJID];
    [iq addAttributeWithName:@"from" stringValue:[[self xmppStream] myJID].full];
    NSXMLElement *query = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"query"];
    [query addAttributeWithName:@"xmlns" stringValue:@"http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items"];
    [iq addChild:query];
    [[self xmppStream] sendElement:iq];`

Comment: NO its not working

Comment: Hello Captain , i have already implemented the one to one chat then  i want to implement group chat and group name is also successfully registered on xmpp server but i cant fetch the registered group's list. please suggest me if you have any idea. Thanks